# Ising to QUBO mapping for quantum annealing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, optimization

I'm trying to solve an optimisation problem by simulating quantum annealing using the path-integral Monte Carlo Metropolis approach. So far I have formulated the problem as an Ising model with the following output:

```
pauli_real_coeff: {'ZIII': 0.31,
                   'IZII': -0.26, 
                   'ZZII': 1.73,
                   'IIZI': 0.38,
                   'ZIZI': 2.05, 
                   'IZZI': 1.87,
                   'IIIZ': -0.24,
                   'ZIIZ': 1.88,
                   'IZIZ': 2.39,
                   'IIZZ': 1.94}

offset:   [3.91]
h_i:     [0.31 -0.26  0.38 -0.24]
J_ij: [[1.09 0.86 1.02 0.94]
          [0.86 1.36 0.93 1.19]
          [1.02 0.93 1.05 0.97]
          [0.94  1.19 0.92 1.15]].
```

However, I'm having trouble mapping this to its equivalent QUBO form. If anyone has any pointers/code (preferably Python) on how I could go about this it'd be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my above question and answering in case someone has a similar question.

The module Dimod by D-Wave Systems has a function, *ising_to_qubo*, in their source code. It can be found in utilities.py here:

https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/projects/dimod/en/latest/_modules/dimod/utilities.html#ising_to_qubo